# Adding methods and values to existing java object

Tags: java, class, object, methods

I'm trying to add a function that add a unique id to an object in java.
I've a function that returns me an object:
`ItemStack is=ent.getKiller().getItemInHand();`
I made a java class that extends ItemStack class and i tryied to cast the object to this class.

```
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import java.util.UUID;
public class UniqueItem extends ItemStack{
    private String uid="";
    public UniqueItem(){
        uid=UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }
    public String getUniqueID(){
        return uid;
    }
}
```

`UniqueItem is=(UniqueItem)ent.getKiller().getItemInHand();`

It produce me an error and i don't undersatand why.
Please help me to solve my problem or give me an alternative solution.
Thanks

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: `ItemStack` is not a `UniqueItem`, thus you cannot cast it that way around.  But `UniqueItem` is a `ItemStack` and you can cast `UniqueItem` to `ItemStack`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a `ClassCastException` at runtime because you are trying to cast an item which is not of type `UniqueItem`

Also, extending the class will not help you. Instead create a wrapper class around ItemStack object which maintains unique ID along with the object.

Try this:

```
// wrapper class
public class UniqueItem {
    ItemStack item;
    private String uid="";
    public UniqueItem(ItemStack item) {
        this.item = item;
        uid=UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }

    public String getUniqueID(){
        return uid;
    }
}
```